# Cognitive Services Speech produces empty file

Tags: c#, nuget-package, azure-cognitive-services

I use Nuget package Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech. I generate ssml and then convert it to mp3. It sometimes produces files of 0 size. Today all the text is translated into files of 0 size. I use Russian voices. What might be the issue?

Comment: Try to use other way to do same things, like using ps1,or restapi. If the results are consistent, then it is likely to be a language factor.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @Jason Pan I think it was some random error and it has gone, thanks for attention

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation on language support, I think the reason you described may be `Russian voices`, which should not be true.

**Official  Doc:**

[Language and voice support for the Speech service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support)

**Suggestion:**

Try to use [official sample code](https://gist.github.com/darrenjrobinson/a203b820dbe359499d58bcec3e2a5abd) to try, or use [restapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech).

You also can share your sample code and file for me (without sensitive info), I can help you to debug.